# How do i tell google to ignore my subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, google-search

I did a search and i found a link to my site... twice. They are exactly the same except one is www and the other is static. How do i tell google to ignore everything in my static domain?

Answer (score 4):

Upload a robots.txt file to the root of the static subdomain. This can block all web spiders including the Googlebot.

You can find instructions on how to format and configure your robots.txt file here:

- http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: good idea. ATM i cant do this bc robots.txt would be shared on both sites.

Answer (score 3):

If your site is served with apache, you can use mod_rewrite to serve a custom robots.txt depending upon the HTTP_HOST variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your DNS control panel, enable only www to point to your site.  You most likely have your DNS settings configured to use * wildcard subdomains.